# aggregate and removes duplicates for some rows

Tags: r, duplicates, aggregate

I have a dataset like

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a","a","b","b","c","d","e","f"),
                 val = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 extracol = c("x",NA,"y","z","t","v","u","p"))

  id val extracol
1  a   1        x
2  a   2     <NA>
3  b   3        y
4  b   4        z
5  c   5        t
6  d   6        v
7  e   7        u
8  f   8        p
```

and I want to sum (and aggregate) the values according to the column id but only for "a". So I want to get something like:

```
  id val extracol
1  a   3        x
2  b   3        y
3  b   4        z
4  c   5        t
5  d   6        v
6  e   7        u
7  f   8        p
```

I really don't care if I get "x" or NA in the extracol. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c("a","a","b","b","c","d","e","f"),
                 val = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 extracol = c("x",NA,"y","z","t","v","u","p"))

# keep only a
a = df%>% filter(id == "a")

# aggregate a
a_agg= a %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(val = sum(val), extracol = first(extracol))

# drop a
df = df %>% filter(id != "a")

# append a
df = rbind(df, a_agg)

df

   id val extracol
1  b   3        y
2  b   4        z
3  c   5        t
4  d   6        v
5  e   7        u
6  f   8        p
7  a   3        x
```

Comment: you actually do not need to group by id if you only have one id value

Comment: true! but maybe useful if instead `a` more values should be treated

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
with(
  df,
  rbind(
    data.frame(
      id = "a",
      val = sum(val[id == "a"]),
      extracol = na.omit(extracol[id == "a"])
    ),
    df[id != "a", ]
  )
)
```

gives

```
  id val extracol
1  a   3        x
3  b   3        y
4  b   4        z
5  c   5        t
6  d   6        v
7  e   7        u
8  f   8        p
```